# Firebase Giving Failed Precondition Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, ionic3

Am getting the ff error with the ff code:
Error:

```
{"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError","__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"macroTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"setTimeout","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}
```

My Code:

```
getOldPosts(forum_id: string, user_id: string, start_key?: string): Promise<Posts[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let olderPosts: Posts[] = [];
      let _5daysAgo = this.dateTime.getFiveDaysAgoDate();

      const postsRef = this.afirestore.collection<Posts>('posts').ref;
      const query = start_key == undefined || start_key == null
        ? postsRef.where('createdDate', '<=', _5daysAgo).where('forumId', '==', forum_id).where('memberId', '==', user_id)
        : postsRef.where('createdDate', '<=', _5daysAgo).where('forumId', '==', forum_id).where('memberId', '==', user_id).startAt(start_key).limit(50);

      query.get().then(
        res => {
          res.docs.forEach(doc => {
            olderPosts.push(doc.data() as ForumPosts);
          });
          resolve(olderPosts.reverse());
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I've tried searching on google but I dont seem to find a solution. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

According to Firestore's documentation in the [Manage indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message) page

> If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map
>   to an existing index, you receive an error.

You can use the Firebase Firestore web console to create the indexes manually for your query.

Otherwise, just run the query and it will throw an error with a URL to the Firestore console where you will get the option to automatically create this compound index.

```
postsRef.where('createdDate', '<=', _5daysAgo).where('forumId', '==', forum_id).where('memberId', '==', user_id)
```

The code block looks like the culprit because it has an equality clause combined with a range clause.

Comment: I agree, best way to create an index seems to bump into the error, inspect the "network" tab in your browser console and you will se an error like this : 

[{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/.../firestore/indexes?create_composite=dNZaW9ClZwcmWN0aW9uR3JvdXBzL2llLXZ....",
        "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
    }
}
]

Just copy and paste the url in your browser and the index will be created :)